# sikuli doesn't find an image on the second monitor

Tags: python, eclipse, windows-7, sikuli, multiple-monitors

Here is my sikuli-related question:
- i have a PC running Win 7, 32bit and two monitors;

My tasks are: find images located on both monitors.

What i have done:

1. identify the screen index:

   - click(Screen(0)) ==> this resulted in a mouse click in the middle of the left screen; this is my main screen
   - click(Screen(1)) ==> this resulted in a mouse click in the middle of the right screen; this is the second monitor
2. find an image located on Screen(0): Screen(0).find("Path to the image") ==> result is a match object
3. find an image located on Screen(1): Screen(1).find("Path to the image") ==> result FindFailed
4. the image is located on Screen(0) at the same position, but call "find" function on Screen(1) ==> result is a match object with position on X = X found at step 2 + the width of Screen(1)

Have you seen this situation: when the image is on the secondary monitor, Sikuli says it is not there, but when the emage is not there Sikuli says it is there.

Is there a windows configuration I have to do or is Sikuli related?

Thank you all,
Irina

Comment: Are you using the same "path to the image" file for both screens? If your two monitors are at all different (different size, different resolution) it can make for difficulty with finding the image on the second screen.

Comment: Yes, the "Path to the image" was the same. Yes, the monitors were also the same. In fact, I updated Sikuli and then everything worked fine. Thanks for your interest.